# Geometry Nodes: How to begin countdown from any frame with a click?

Tags: geometry-nodes, timer

This is going to be a very specific question, about a very specific problem.

I am trying to make an interactive game, similar to Who wants to be a Millionaire, where I want to have Blender run constantly for a couple of hours as a background and interactive menu to show questions and different actions. There I also want to have a countdown timer, which I can start at any time during the game with a boolean switch or something as simple, basically just a click of a button in the modifier panel.

I found this tutorial for a simple countdown timer, [Make a Countdown Timer Node in Blender Geometry Nodes! by Johnny Matthews](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=e4-5T-zdpZ8), which I converted to show minutes, seconds and hundredths of seconds, and to have specific timer active or a custom time limit active.

My node tree:

1. Countdown
   [image: Countdown nodes]
2. Numbers
   [image: Number nodes]
3. Output text
   [image: Text output nodes]

But the problem is, it can countdown only from the first frame, and I don't want to constantly restart it.

I tried to use Capture Attribute node before geometry output and add the attribute to countdown, but anyhow I do it, the timer goes ether to 0. I don't know how to program either, so if the solution is as simple as a couple lines of code, I don't know what to write there.

Blend file used:
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you add this to your subtract node:

[image]

you get this if you click on restart:

[image]

Comment: I see, thank you so much! I would also ask on how to make it restart on only True output, but if it works why fix it. XD

Comment: I got it now, when I removed nodes for restart and put the switch into first Capture attribute, it turned into a start countdown switch, which is even better to be honest. XDDD