# Activating geo-node switch using a change in integer (or float) value

Tags: geometry-nodes

I'm trying to make an animation for a scoreboard, where the animation plays whenever the score value (I'm using an integer) changes. So, whenever it changes, the animation based on Tangent function plays and score switches.

The desired result:

[image]

Animation has to be continuously moving forward or backwards like in the gif.

Blender is running timeline in real time, so no key-frames can be used, only with nodes. Thus I remembered that I have asked a question for repeating a timer: [Geometry Nodes: How to begin countdown from any frame with a click?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/310597/geometry-nodes-how-to-begin-countdown-from-any-frame-with-a-click)
where the answer could be used as an on switch with boolean value, and it works. Whenever boolean value is False the animation plays, but a new problem showed up. When I restart the animation, it rotates back to it's previous position, and doesn't add to the previous score.

[image]

Here is the node setup for rotation with animation (for rotation itself here:[Geometry Nodes: How limit function and activate the said function with an integer change or a click?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/310975/geometry-nodes-how-limit-function-and-activate-the-said-function-with-an-intege/311025#311025)):[image]

And here is the node setup for the animation to start based on answer in the beginning:[image]

The blend file:[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The setup is very simple:

[image]

- Get the value and pass it to a *Smooth Change* group which uses a simulation zone to remember the old value and gradually move towards the new one; since we want a separate wheel for each digit, I encode them as one point per digit, and use *Radius* to store the digit's value.
- Import or dynamically create a *Digit Wheel* for the visual effect.
- Map the $[0, 9]$ range of a single digit to a $[0, τ - {τ \over 10}]$ ($0...9$ range multiplied by ${360° \over 10} = 36°$) and set it as a rotation of the wheel.

[image]

**Smooth Change** custom group:

[image]

- First I make a Mesh Line of 7 points. Unfortunately you can't have more points, because there are no integer math operations in geonodes, and above $2^{24} = 16777216$ float precision becomes worse than $1$ (it will misread the last digit).
- I convert it to points so it's as lightweight as possible in a simulation (that's why I use radius instead of a new attribute) and set the radius of all points to $0$ to initialize the roller at all zeroes.
- I maintain *Velocity* in the simulation to simulate inertia for realistic effect.
- *Number to Digits* converts currently set integer to separate points each representing a digit, from the units digit to the most significant digit (first point is last digit) - that's why the Mesh Line's offset is negative. The actual value of a digit is stored as the radius. So the same format as in the output of the simulation zone.

[image]

- *Engine* defines the algorithm of the transition between two values of a digit.

[image]

If you want the rotations to go the short way between $0$ and $9$, you need to implement it in the *Engine*. If you want more acceleration, increase left multiplier, if you want more friction, decrease the right multiplier, if you don't want to overshoot - you need to adjust friction based on the distance to target ("other angle").

[image]

For completeness, this is the *Digit Wheel* I made:

[image]

Comment: Yes, this actually works! I have made a new node tree based on your setup and put it into mine. For anyone who is going to use this too, a couple of points: refresh your node tree with this setup, otherwise a bug in a form of geometry duplication will occur, and use values 0.1 to have a similar animation to the first gif. And that's it, thank you so much! The fact that it generally is a simple node tree of like 30 nodes is great for my pretty much novice in geo-nodes brain! Thank you again, so so much!